# Get result of joining as array

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have these 2 tables:

languages

```
id | name
 1 | java
 2 | php
 3 | c++
 4 | javascript
```

developers

```
 id|name
 1 | John
 2 | Jack
```

And a associative

lang_dev

```
id|dev_id|lang_id
 1|   1  |   1
 2|   1  |   2
 3|   2  |   3
 4|   2  |   4
```

I can simply join them using something like this:

```
SELECT dev.*, lang.name as lang_name
FROM developers as dev
LEFT JOIN lang_dev as ld ON dev.id = ld.dev_id
LEFT JOIN languages as lang ON lang.id = ld.tag_id
WHERE dev.id = 1
```

That returns:

```
id| name | lang_name |
1 | john |   java    |
1 | john |   php     |
```

What I want is to get one unique row like this:

```
id | name | lang_name|
 1 | john | java, php|
```

Also if it is possible, I would like to get it in a array:

```
Array {
   ["id"]=>
    string() "1"
   ["name"]=>
    string() "john"
   ["lang_name"]=> Array {
    string() "java"
    string() "php"    
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`group_concat`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) should do the trick:

```
SELECT   name, GROUP_CONCAT(lange_name)
FROM     developers d
JOIN     lang_dev ld ON d.id = ld.dev_id
JOIN     languages l ON ld.lang_id = l.id
GROUP BY name
```

Comment: Exactly what he needed. And to separate using array just use `explode()` e.g `explode(',', $row['GROUP_CONCAT(lang.name)']);`